# Can we "safely" assume that quantum computing systems will be finite-dimensional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-computer

This is a common assumption in the study of quantum computation to assume that the quantum systems involved are finite-dimensional, since qubits lives in the two-dimensional Hilbert space.

According to [Roman Gielerak and Marek Sawerwain](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5239), the quantum registers corresponding to a quantum computing machine with coherent pulses of light must have an infinite-dimensional character.

I am looking for arguments for and against the hypothesis that finite-dimensional structures are sufficient to study quantum computation.